# How can i update laravel pagination records depends on select option value per page using laravel and ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, pagination

my target is to make a filter with select option menu and pagination using ajax , the select option to choose between 10 ,15, 20 , 25 products per page and updating at the same time the laravel default pagination with new records like from 10 links to 5 links depend on the select option result. the problem is i can filter products per page with the select option but i can't update laravel pagination records.

```
//the select option list
<label>Show</label>
 <select id="selectAmount">
    <option id="tweleve" value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
    <option id="fifteen" value="15">15</option>
    <option id="thirty"  value="20">20</option>
 </select>






 //the view products.blade.php
 <div class="products">
     <ul id="prods">
       @foreach($products as $product)
         <li>{{ $product->title  }}</li> 
         <li>{{ $product->image  }}</li>
         <li>{{ $product->price  }}</li>
       @endforeach  
     </ul>
     {{  $products->links()  }}
 </div>





    //the partial view partials.products.php
    <li>{{ $product->title  }}</li> 
    <li>{{ $product->image  }}</li>
    <li>{{ $product->price  }}</li>    




  // the route
  Route::get('products', 'ProductController@index');





 //the controller
public function index(Request $request)
{

        if($request->ajax()) {
            $amount = $request->input('amount');
            $products = Product::paginate($amount);
            $list = [];

            foreach($products as $product){
                $html =  view('partials.prodperpage')
                        ->with('product', $product)
                        ->render();

                $list[] = $html;        
            }

            return response()->json($list);
        }


        $products = Product::paginate(9);
        return view('pages.products', compact('products'));

}


 //the ajax request
$('#selectAmount').change( function() {

    var selected = $('#selectAmount option:selected');
    var myurl = '/products';
    $('#prods').empty();

     if(selected.val() <= 30) {
       var amount = selected.val();

       $.ajax({
            type: 'GET', 
            url: myurl,
            data: {amount:amount},
            success: function(data) {       
                $('#prods').append(data);
            }
        });

    }

});
```

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: Nope there is no errors

Comment: You are redirecting your control to view page and again you are calling that controller in ajax, so in ajax redirecting is not working, you need to check $request->ajax() in your controller

Comment: Let me check for it

Comment: it doesn't work !!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get your pagination works after an Ajax request i think this question has already been answered here
[Laravel 5: How to Paginate an Ajax Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31268227/laravel-5-how-to-paginate-an-ajax-response?rq=1)

Comment: i read this question and answer before it's not the right choice for me , all i want to link both pagination and option select , when i select to filter the quantity of the products to 15, 20, 25 products also the default laravel pagination update.

Comment: On one comment above, you said that ther's no error so how do you know  that it doesn't work ?

Comment: What's the result or the reaction which indicate you that the pagination doesn't work properly?

Comment: my target is to make a filter with both option select menu and pagination using ajax , option select to choose between 10 ,15, 20 , 25 products per page and updating at the same time the laravel default pagination with new records , hope this example make it more clear to understand me.